# MYSQL: Update column from varchar to float value not same

Tags: mysql

I want to update a float column in one table from a varchar in another table but when I update the value is slightly different.

For example the number is: **1284773** as varchar, but become **1284770** as float. The last digit always become 0.

My query is:

```
UPDATE sales s
SET
S.item_comission =
(
    SELECT REF.comission
    FROM ref_comission REF
    WHERE REF.rv_id = S.item_id
          AND REF.parent_id = S.item_sub_id
)
WHERE S.item_type = 'P';
```

**item_comission** in Table **sales** is S is a float

while **comission** in Table **ref_comission** is varchar (20)

> > > > THIS IS THE ACTUAL VALUE: 1284773 <<< Strange, even I change directly, the value still back to 1284770

Comment: so my query should be UPDATE sales S SET S.item_comission = (SELECT CAST(REF.comission AS FLOAT) FROM ref_comission REF WHERE REF.rv_id = S.item_id AND REF.parent_id = S.item_sub_id) WHERE S.item_type = 'P' <=== ? this one doesnt work

Comment: i'm using MYSQL

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually, it does: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Floating point storage is non exact.  If you need exact precision, use a fixed type like integer or decimal.  I'm not sure we can fix your situation if you've already stored the information as floating point.

Comment: @MiljenMikic You're right...I was going off a really old SO question.  Anyway, I think the problem here is floating point storage itself; it's not exact.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried This way

```
UPDATE S
    SET
       item_comission = CAST(REF.comission AS FLOAT)
    FROM Sales S
       INNER JOIN ref_comission REF
          ON REF.rv_id = S.item_id
             AND REF.parent_id = S.item_sub_id
       WHERE S.item_type = 'P'
```

Comment: i did, this was my first query, the result are the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    UPDATE Sales
    SET
    item_comission = CAST(round(REF.comission,-1) AS FLOAT)
    FROM Sales S
    INNER JOIN ref_comission REF
    ON REF.rv_id = S.item_id
    AND REF.parent_id = S.item_sub_id
    WHERE S.item_type = 'P'
```

Comment: it says error after FLOAT, seems my mysql doesnt recognize float